# Dock with launcher

Tags: dock

I was wondering if there is any dock such as AWN that has an available plug-in for an OS X Launchpad-style application launcher?

I tried searching online, but not much came up in terms of what I was looking for

For reference: http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT5548/en_US/HT5548_03-osx_9-launchpad-overview-001-en.png

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you choose one of followings.

```
ubuntu-dock

cairo-dock

docky

awn

plank
```

It's just i suggest, perhaps there are many dock softwares that i don't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

The Unity dash now has functionality similar to what you are describing here.

Open Unity Search and switch to the Apps Lens (**Super+a** for quick access). 
[image: Unity Search Apps Lens]

IMO it's better than the OS X version because of recent apps, filters, etc. and it's bundled with file/folder search.

To my knowledge Cairo dock does not offer this kind of functional.  I have tried to change the style of the applications menu but have not been successful.  If the applications menu would appear as a slider that would be nice but as of right now you can only get the standard apps menu view. 
 Cheers